# Can I convert rows containing hourly observations into columns for daily rows using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series holding hourly observations of a metric. I would like to transform that into a series holding daily observations with each daily observation row having 24 hourly columns.

As an example, I would like to convert

```
                 value

2018-05-12 12:00 45
2018-05-12 13:00 46
2018-05-12 14:00 47
```

to

```
           value_12 value_13 value_14
2018-05-12 45       46       47
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this using builtin methods in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [45, 46, 47]}, index=['2018-05-12 12:00', '2018-05-12 13:00', '2018-05-12 14:00'])
```

Then you can extract the date and hour:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).date
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).hour
```

Now just group by the date, and create a Series:

```
>>> df.groupby([df.date]).apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g.value.values, index='value_' + g.hour.astype(str)))
hour    value_12    value_13    value_14
date            
2018-05-12  45  46  47
```